# How do I loop through all compositions in an After Effects project?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

How does one loop through all the compositions in the currently opened After Effects project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `app.project.items` holds all the compositions, and folders in the currently opened project. So this way I can loop through all of these, and I also have to check for whether it is a composition (since it can be a folder as well).

```
for (var i = 1; i <= app.project.numItems; i++) {
    if (app.project.item(i) instanceof CompItem) {
        // Do stuff with the composition.
        // app.project.item(i) is the composition.
    }
}
```